# StreamWriter gives less lines that it should

Tags: c#, matrix, streamwriter

I'm practicing C# programming for an exam, but I can't solve a problem, that's why I'm asking for your help.

I have a matrix (50x50) full of strings (RGB codes) [it's name: `kep`].

I tried to write the matrix to a TXT file, but it gives less lines than it should.

```
StreamWriter fajl = new StreamWriter(@"..\..\..\keretes.txt");
int ciklusok = 0;

for (int y = 0; pixelek > y; y++)
{
    for (int x = 0; pixelek > x; x++)
    {
        fajl.WriteLine(kep[x, y]);
        ciklusok++;
    }
}
```

`StreamWriter` writes the TXT "successfully" but it has only 2412 lines (also the value in the last line had been split).

The `ciklusok` variable gives 2500 (it's the right number).

Does anyone know why `StreamWriter` isn't writing correctly?

Comment: Did you close the `StreamWriter` before check? I guess it will be flushing issue.

Answer (score 1):

Try  to wrap StreamWriter in **using** block. Because, you are not calling `Close()` and `Close()` - **closes** stream, and internally **flush** operation is also performed. Using statement automatically calls `Close()` method.

> Flush - Clears all buffers for the current writer and causes any
>   buffered data to be written to the underlying stream.

```
using (StreamWriter fajl = new StreamWriter(@"..\..\..\keretes.txt"))
{
    int ciklusok = 0;

    for (int y = 0; pixelek > y; y++)
    {
        for (int x = 0; pixelek > x; x++)
        {
             fajl.WriteLine(kep[x, y]);
             ciklusok++;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Though it may be a right answer, care to say **why**?

Comment: Thanks for your help, and for giving information to me! This solution works too!

Comment: @FábiánAttila Glad to help. It is always recommended to use `Using` with `disposable` objects. It automatically closes and disposes the object for sure. And don't forget to mark this as the answer , if it was really solved your problem.